# How to test our web app on an iMac if we don't have one?

Tags: test-design, web-application

We are a software development company that is building a new web application. Part of our responsiveness test, we need to check how it would look like on iMac 21.5" and iMac 27".

Problem is, we don't have iMacs (or any screen with that size). What's the best way to tackle this challenge?

Comment: You can use Browserstack.

Comment: @TESTasy Any free alternatives?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach is to use services that provide *remote Selenium server capabilities* and allow to specify an operating system, version, browser, browser version and other parameters in the desired capabilities. Today, there are two major players on that front:

- [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/start)
- [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/)

Another possible way to approach the problem is to fire up a virtual machine with your desired operating system and have a Selenium node for your Selenium server configured, see more at [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) documentation page.

Comment: Would Selenium help in testing the Design and Responsiveness of a web application?

Comment: @TESTasy it can be certainly used that way though I've personally never specifically used it for that - only to some extent may be.

Comment: @Testasy  you can change the size of the driver under test by using driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height)); then refresh the page that should tricker the responsive view

Comment: I get that part. What I'd like to know is how will selenium decide that the design of the page that has loaded is what it should be like? How will it know which element is suppose to be exactly where and check if it is there or not? How will selenium know if design isn't correct and inform you about it?

Comment: @TESTasy these are good questions. Not sure we should talk about it here in comments though - it is getting a bit off-topic. Please consider creating a separate question where we can rightfully discuss the topic, would love to join the discussion and brainstorm ideas. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments. I'll need to do some more investigation.